# How to allow button click events if window in the background

Tags: c#, winforms, events, process

I have an application, **`ParentApp`**, which launches another application, **`ChildApp`**.

`ParentApp` displays a form while the `ChildApp` is running - just a kind of *Childapp is currently running* display with a Cancel button which kills `ChildApp`.

I want `ParentApp` to be unusable while `ChildApp` is running, so whenever someone clicks on `ParentApp` I want to bring the `ChildApp` to the foreground, which is fine.

So I've added this event handler to the `ParentApp` which responds to the `Activated` event of the form.

```
private void ParentAppForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr childHwnd = _childApp.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(childHwnd );
}
```

(`GotFocus` didn't seem to work)

Unfortunately, if the user clicks the `Cancel` button on the `ParentAppForm`, the event handler for that button is never hit, because the `Activated` event fires first and sets the foreground window to another process.

Is there around this - to allow the button event to fire even though the application is not in the foreground?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick workaround, you could check whether the mouse pointer in inside the area described by the **`Button.Bounds`** when the Form is activated.

You can translate the mouse pointer position to the `Form.Bounds` coordinates using [PointToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.PointToClient);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) with the [Cursor.Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) coordinates.

Something like this:

```
private void ParentAppForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.button1.Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        ChildForm.Close();  //Or ChildApp.Kill()
    else
        ChildForm.BringToFront();  //Or SetForegroundWindow(ChildApp.Handle)
}
```